# Guessing game with 5 chances in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, while-loop

This is my code:

```
import random

letters = ['a','g','s','s','c','v','e','g','d','g']

random_letter = random.choice(letters)

guesses_left = 5
while guesses_left > 0:
  guess = input("Your guess: ")
  if guess == random_letter:
    print ("You win!")
    break
  guesses_left -= 1 
else:
  print ("You lose.")
```

My question: Why am I able to type other types than strings? For example, if I run the code and answer with an integer I don't get error. If this problem is not fixable, is there a better way to create this type of game?

Comment: why wouldn't you? anything you type in for ```input``` is a string including numbers. only when you do ```int(input("Your Guess"))``` it will be a number

Comment: What *is* the actual problem? What error were you actually expecting? Keep in mind that `input` always returns a `str` type.

Comment: you can set conditions so the input isn't accepted if the input is not a letter

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
It appears that you have not yet worked through any materials on input type conversion and validity checking.  "teach me this basic programming feature" is a question for your instructor or other materials, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @coderoftheday How can I do this? I want the code to only accept letters as answers

Comment: i've added it as an answer

Comment: *Why should it be a problem* if the input isn't a letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.isalpha` checks to see if the string is all characters

```
import random

letters = ['a','g','s','s','c','v','e','g','d','g']

random_letter = random.choice(letters)

guesses_left = 5
while guesses_left > 0:
    guess = input("Your guess: ")
    if guess.isalpha():
        if guess == random_letter:
            print ("You win!")
            break
        else:
            print ("You lose.")
        guesses_left -= 1
    else:
        print('This is not a letter')
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution asks for input as long as its not a letter. . .

```
import random

letters = ['a', 'g', 's', 's', 'c', 'v', 'e', 'g', 'd', 'g']

random_letter = random.choice(letters)


guesses_left = 5
while guesses_left > 0:

    guess = input("Your guess: ")

   #check if the input is a letter if not ask for input again
    while not guess.isalpha():
        guess = input("Pleass only enter letters")
    if guess == random_letter:
        print("You win!")
        break
    guesses_left -= 1

else:
    print("You lose.")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type a character using `input` you will be entering a string. This is the default behaviour for `input`.

The reason that you don't get an error is because you are comparing whatever you type to the content in `letters`.

E.g., if I you entered '1' as a guess, your code would check if the string '1' is in `letters`, which it is not.

To throw an error if the user enters a number, you could change your code to:

```
  guess = input("Your guess: ")
  if guess.isnumeric():
     raise ValueError("Only letters are allowed")
  if guess == random_letter:
    print ("You win!")
    break
  guesses_left -= 1 
else:
  print ("You lose.")
```